# AWS SQS dead-letter queue redrive policy

Tags: amazon-web-services, queue, amazon-sqs

In my system there is a main-queue and dead-letter-queue.

When any message failed in main-queue it goes to dead-letter-queue.

Reason of failing message in main-queue sometime random not critical i.e. message can be processed if reattempt from the main-queue.

In my system there are 3 attempt to any failed message, meaning will send message to main-queue from dead-letter-queue only 3 times.

> **How can i track the message whether its 3rd attempt is exhausted and there is no need to send it back to main-queue for processing (will keep in dlq till it expire)?**

Comment: I don't think the message goes to Dead Letter Queue for every attempt failure. If you have configured the number of re-attempts using `x.RetryCountBeforeSendingToErrorQueue = 3;` property, it simply does retry attempts as configured (3 attempts) and then it moves the message to Dead Letter Queue.

Comment: Continuation to my comment above. Here is the [official documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/SQSDeveloperGuide/sqs-dead-letter-queues.html#:~:text=The%20redrive%20policy%20specifies%20the%20source%20queue%2C%20the%20dead%2Dletter%20queue%2C%20and%20the%20conditions%20under%20which%20Amazon%20SQS%20moves%20messages%20from%20the%20former%20to%20the%20latter%20if%20the%20consumer%20of%20the%20source%20queue%20fails%20to%20process%20a%20message%20a%20specified%20number%20of%20times)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the property [ApproximateReceiveCount](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/APIReference/API_ReceiveMessage.html#:%7E:text=ApproximateFirstReceiveTimestamp%20%E2%80%93%20Returns%20the,in%20milliseconds) from MessageAttributes in `SQSEvent.SQSMessage`